# Creating a virtual file from string

Tags: php, file

I'm using a library which take as a parameter a file to open it with `fopen` and read it with `fseek` and `fread`

Here what the constructor look like :

```
public function __construct($file) {
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->h = fopen($this->file, "r");

    $stats = fstat($this->h);
    $this->size = $stats['size'];
}
```

The data which i like to give to this constructor come from a database, so basically i have a variable with some text in it.

**Is there a way to emulate a file from the variable containing the data ?**

I have tried to use stream with `php://memory` without any luck (`$stats = fstat($this->h)` = 0) :

```
$data = " my string data";
$virtualfile = 'php://memory';
$h = fopen($path, "rw+");
fwrite($h, $data);

$lib = new MyLib($virtualfile);
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [data:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) url wrapper

```
$data = " my string data";
$virtualfile='data:text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($data);
$lib = new MyLib($virtualfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fopen` returns you a `$h` pointer to the file - you should pass this pointer to your class to keep working on it, so:

```
$lib = new MyLib($h);
```

and constructor:

```
public function __construct($h) {
    $this->h = $h;

    $stats = fstat($this->h);
    $this->size = $stats['size'];
}
```

Comment: Ican't modify the library to fit my need. It take a filepath , can't do anything else.

Comment: You cannot pass to the library a path to the `php://memory` - pointer will change. You have to save file then in filesystem.